# MySQL access slow from windows clients on virtual server

Tags: mysql, windows-7, java

I have an installation of UniCenta open source POS on three till computers at a pub I used to work at.

The clients are pointed to a virtual server running CentOS 6 and MySQL 5.6.39 with phpMyAdmin for management.

The application is written in Java and runs against MySQL

A couple of months ago the installation started running really slowly with buttons on the screen taking several seconds to respond, in a busy pub this is a serious problem.

I tried changing settings in my.cnf on the server to tweak performance of the MySQL server, thinking this was the issue initially, but this made no difference.

I have upgraded to the latest version of the UniCenta software to see if that would resolve things, but still no joy.

I thought I would try the client from my Mac running OS-X El Capitan and this works perfectly without any slowness.

I have tried installing different versions of Java on the client computers, but this has had no effect.

I have changed the skip_name_resolve to on after seeing this mentioned in several posts online, but this still does not resolve the issue.

I have tested a windows 7 virtual PC on my mac against a local database and this works fine without slowing down, so the issue is somewhere between the clients and the virtual server.

I have tried disabling NetBIOS over TCP/IP on the Windows clients, but this makes no difference.

I am thinking that a wireshark trace is the next step in figuring out the problem but thought I would post this up and see if anyone else might have some clever ideas regarding the Windows 7 TCP/IP stack or other networking issues that might be causing the problem.

18-02-2018
Further to this, I have installed the client software on another Windows 7 machine at the same location as the tills and this works perfectly against the VPS hosted database.

I have now copied the VPS database over to a local database and the three till computers work perfectly well against this local database.

The issue seems to be with certain computers when accessing the VPS hosted database.

Wireshark doesn't show any issues with connectivity between the clients and the server so troubleshooting is problematic.

Further update:
Possible fix is to disable an auto-refresh setting on the application. This setting performs a big refresh task every time it runs and on a number of screen re-loads therefore creating large amounts of traffic to the SQL server.

Having disabled this option seems to have resolved the speed issue and the application is running normally and responding in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to disable an auto-refresh setting in the application. This was to do with the number of SQL connections this creates and it may be possible to tune the MySQL server polling settings to deal with the number of requests that happen with the auto-refresh settings.